# Hidden input (html form confirmation) - Server side script? (php)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I'm writing a site in PHP.
And I have a simple registration form.

```
<form>
<label...></label> <input .../>
</form>
```

I want to add a confirmation field:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hiddeninput' value="jn3kjnv3kjvn35">
```

But how does this code look on the server side?
Do I need to save every hidden value to the database whenever registration form is loaded?

I'm trying to make sure the form is not being filled in by bots.

That's why I need a random hidden value that is unique for every form submission.

Suppose every time I generate the registration page - I generate the unique value for "hidden" field.

When the user submits the form - how do I compare the submitted value to the one that was generated (as once it's generated - it's not stored anywhere in the site).

Comment: You need to give the hidden fields names too.

Comment: "Do I need to save every hidden value to the database whenever registration form is loaded?" - That depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use `Ruby on Rails` framework that solves it out of the box.

Comment: This is not an answer. Even if you start using a different framework unless you'll update your question it's not appropriate behaviour to mark an already accepted answer as not and accept your own answer.

Comment: Well, I wish when I looked for an answer, someone actually told me about Ruby on Rails. Because of answers like yours, I spent a lot of time reading books about every possible framework until I finally found Rails. More importantly, your answer doesn't follow MVC convention. So... Yeah. I think when people read this question it's more of a use for them to know they could switch to Rails than follow your answer and try to reinvent the wheel and manually create CSRF tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly , you should use a function that generates a random string (`hash` for example)
and `sessions` to "remember" this string.
Aftet submitting the form , you'll check the INPUT's value and cross it with the SESSION's value.

For instance:

**Form.php**

```
<?php
 $hash = md5(time());
 $_SESSION['form_xx'] = $hash; //in case you have more than one form.
?>
<form method='post' action='do.php'>
..
..
<input type='hidden' name='secret_key' value='<?=$hash?>'>
</form>
```

**do.php**

```
if($_POST['secret_key'] == $_SESSION['form_xx']) //Just make sure your making the posted value SAFE
 //He's ok.
else
 die("arggg...those hackers");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a name to the field, too. It works like pretty much any other HTML field.